# A large and open source data set for research

Tags: hadoop, dataset, hive, cloudera, impala

Please help me to find a massive data set for data mining research project.

It would be very helpful if you suggest me any **search engines** data (Google/yahoo user search history) or **Wikipedia's user viewed statistics** or **twitter's user tweet** data set.

i am working on hadoop framework and databases so for that i want millions of records in each table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is million songs data set.

```
http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/
```

If you want to extract tweets, I would suggest Twitter's Streaming API.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Comment: Hey thanks Data-KeeG.
But It would be very great if u suggest me some search engine data set or twitter tweets data set.

Because further i want to work on profile based web personalization.

It will help me to mine the users interest and i can work on search results.

Thanks again.